# Fish shell script: add a list as a function's argument

Tags: shell, fish

I would like to pass a list of variable length as a parameter into a fish function called and defined within a fish script, similar to how `$argv` is a list on the top level of a fish script I guess.

```
function main_function
   function f --argument xs
      echo "called f"
      echo $xs     
   end
    set xs "one" "two" "three";
    f $xs
end
```

calling `function --help` mentions the `--inherit-variable` option. While setting the option causes the `xs` variable within the f's scope to be the full list, it makes a dumb copy at the point where the function is defined. I need the variable to be copied when f is called, however.

```
function main_function
   set xs "one" "two" "three";
   function f --inherit-variable xs
      echo "called f"
      echo $xs     
   end
   f $xs
end
```

Comment: You can access the function's arguments using `$argv`, from within the function. Does that help?

Answer (score 1):

As @ridiculous_fish mentioned in the comments, `$argv` is defined by and available in any function, regardless of its "level".  So if you need to "copy" a list into the function when it is called (vs. *defined*), just pass the item(s) as argument(s) and access using `$argv`.

For instance:

```
function outer
    set --show argv
    set xs "one" "two" "three"
    function inner
        set --show argv
    end
    inner $xs
end
```

Calling `outer` with no arguments will return:

```
$argv: set in local scope, unexported, with 0 elements
$argv: set in local scope, unexported, with 3 elements
$argv[1]: |one|
$argv[2]: |two|
$argv[3]: |three|
```

But calling `outer four five size` will result in:

```
$argv: set in local scope, unexported, with 3 elements
$argv[1]: |four|
$argv[2]: |five|
$argv[3]: |six|
$argv: set in local scope, unexported, with 3 elements
$argv[1]: |one|
$argv[2]: |two|
$argv[3]: |three|
```

Each function's `$argv` is distinct, even though they are nested.